# In Google Map SDK for IOS, how do I change the bearing of the map without animating it?

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I can change the bearing of my map using

```
[googleMapView animateToBearing:0.5];
```

but how does one do this so the change is instantaneous, with no animation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grab the current camera position, change the bearing, then set the view's camera position:

```
GMSCameraPosition *myCamera = googleMapView.camera;
GMSCameraPosition *myNewCamera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:myCamera.targetAsCoordinate.latitude longitude:myCamera.targetAsCoordinate.longitude zoom:myCamera.zoom bearing:0.5 viewingAngle:myCamera.viewingAngle];
googleMapView.camera = myNewCamera;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no direct option like movetobearing, one can use the above mentioned approach. Another option is to use `[googleMapView animateToBearing:0.5];` and then set the animation duration to a very low value , say like 0.0001f, which gives the visual effect of a movement

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: 0.0001f] forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];
[mapView_ animateToBearing:0.5];
[CATransaction commit];
```

Answer (score 0):

For a smoother and a transitioned update try this (view is a GMSMapView)

```
[self.view animateToCameraPosition:[GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:coordinate.latitude longitude:coordinate.longitude zoom:15 bearing:bearing viewingAngle:45]];
```